# How to get Window from handle in WPF

Tags: wpf, window

I have a WPF UI , On click of a button I am starting threads .
I want to read few txtbox values on the UI from the thread and want to update a textbox on the UI with the status of the thread

I am trying to pass the handle of the UI to the thread and get the window back from the handle ( as we do in MFC) and updat the UI.

I am able to get the handle as " IntPtr ParentHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;"

But dont know how to get the window from the handle .

OR

Is there anyother way i can update and retreive values on WPF UI from a thread .

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any handles. Just pass object references. You can create the thread using the `ParameterizedThreadStart` class, which takes an `object` parameter. So you can define an object that contains members for all the values you want to pass to the thread, instead of having the thread retrieve them from the UI. Also, you can pass a reference to your window class, so when the thread is done (or to update the status), you can just use that reference (remember to use the Dispatcher to update the controls (in WinForms you'd have done `this.Invoke`).

This could look like the following:

```
public class WPFWindow ...
{
    private class ThreadData
    {
        public int Value1;
        public string Value2;
        public WPFWindow Window;
    }

    ....

    private void StartThread()
    {
        ThreadData tdata = new ThreadData();
        tdata.Value1 = 42;
        tdata.Value2 = "Hello World!";
        tdata.Window = this;

        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t.Start(tdata);
    }

    private void ThreadMethod(object data)
    {
        ThreadData tdata = (ThreadData)data;

        // ... process values here

        // Update controls
        if(tdata.Window.textbox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            // The calling thread owns the dispatcher, and hence the UI element
            tdata.Window.textbox.AppendText(...);
        }
        else
        {
            // Invokation required
            tdata.Window.textbox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm writing this blindly without having testet this in WPF. This is, however, the way I do it all the time in WinForms.

Comment: thanks for the answer , just one question 
what would be the implementaion of the delgate in the else case

Comment: The delegate (which can also be an anonymous method) would just update the respective control. I guess you can also check the Dispatcher for the Window itself and then put all the code updating controls into the delegate. A sample can be found here: http://ascendedguard.com/2007/08/anonymous-functions-and-invoking-in-wpf.html

Answer (score 0):

For anybody (like me) comming here in the actual intent of retrieving a `Window` from a window handle (HWND)

## First of all

You can only get `Window` instances of windows of your current process. You can't get a `Window` instance for a window of a foreign process.

## Getting the window

Create a new `WindoCollectionExtensions.cs` and paste this extensions method:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace My.Code;

public static class WindowCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Window GetWindow(this WindowCollection list, int hwnd)
    {
        foreach(Window wnd in list)
        {
            if (new WindowInteropHelper(wnd).Handle == hwnd)
            {
                return wnd;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

With this in place you can easily get the `Window` like this:

```
Window window = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.GetWindow(hwnd);
```